# Add column to multiindex as ratio of two other level=0 columns

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a `DataFrame` with a `MultiIndex`:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['field1', 'field2'], ['product1','product2','product3']],
           codes=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2]],
           names=['metric', 'label'])
```

Having `import pandas as pd`, I am able to reference and use:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
data.loc[:,idx['field1',:]].tail()
#and
data.loc[:,idx['field2',:]].tail()
```

Now, I am a bit stuck when I think about adding a `field3` to my DataFrame (`data`) which I want to be a ratio of the two fields:

```
#This works and gives me the output I'd want:
(data.loc[:,idx['field1']] / (data.loc[:,idx['field2']]))
```

But, it is unclear how to add this into my multi-index as both of these commands:

```
data.loc[:,['field3',:]] =  quarterly_data.loc[:,idx['accountsreceivable']].div(quarterly_data.loc[:,idx['revenue']]/90)

data.loc[:,['field3']] =  quarterly_data.loc[:,idx['accountsreceivable']].div(quarterly_data.loc[:,idx['revenue']]/90)
```

Do not work. They give me a new `level=0` MultiIndex which is `field3` but a `level=1` Multi-Index which applies to only one column where the `level=1` is `''`.

Eg:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['field1', 'field2', 'field3'], ['product1', 'product2','']],...
```

Now, If I specify:

```
data.loc[:,idx['field3','product1']] =  data.loc[:,idx['field1','product1']]/(data.loc[:,idx['field2','product1']])
```

It works, but just for `product1`. How would I do it for ALL `:` products at once? Iterating over all `product{s}` seems too non-pandas to be an acceptable answer.
I also tried using `div` in place of `/` but it did not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Create `MultiIndex` for new DataFrame and add to original:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df = (data.loc[:,idx['field1']] / (data.loc[:,idx['field2']]))
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['new'], df.columns])

data = data.join(df)
```

Another way is create columns by reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), processing and then reshape back:

```
df = data.stack()
df['new'] = df['field1'] / df['field2']

df = df.unstack()
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I need to assume there is a cleaner way to do this? What if I have MANY columns I want to add that are all various linear combinations of a few other?

Comment: @jasonm - There is possible loop by each Series separately, but I think it is worse solution.